# How To Display Byte[] As Picture In MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image

I have a model that contains a Byte[] type property .I want to display this property in MVC View in  html tag.What approach I can use to display this image?

Comment: When you call *"ASP.NET MVC 4"* framework as just *"MVC"*, it is like referring to IE as *"the internet"*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create an action on your controller to return the file response:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult ViewFile()
    {
        byte[] bytes;
        string mime;

        return File(bytes, mime);
    }
}
```

You can then display the image like so:

```
<img src="/mycontroller/viewfile" />
```

EDIT: 
A detailed example:

```
public class Photo
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
}

public class PhotoController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new List<Photo> { new Photo { ID = 1, Title = "first" }, new Photo { ID = 2, Title = "second" }});
    }
    public ActionResult Photo(int ID)
    {
        return File(GetPhotoBytes(ID), "image/jpg");
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Photo>
@foreach (var photo in Model)
{   
    <img src="@Url.Action("photo", "photo", new { ID = photo.ID })" title="@photo.Title" /> 
}
```

Comment: I am using this model as List<Model>.In view I display all property in table.so how is it possible use this action result to model?

Comment: You could consider embedding the image but this can have a serious impact on performance. http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/

Answer (score 9):

This is what I need to do in my project:
For each instance of my object collection I put below tag in Razor View

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetPhoto", new { photoId = Model.PhotoId })" />
```

And then in Controller I added a Action:

```
public ActionResult GetPhoto(int photoId)
{
    byte[] photo = GetPhotoFromDb(photoId);
    return File(photo, "image/jpeg"); }
```